# SE manipulation recruitment saga Pt. II

Tags: discussion, spam, abuse, recruitment

First, please read Pt. I of this story:

[This guy tried to recruit me as a stooge for manipulating SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390811/196834)

---

I've decided to counter-fish our friend Mr. Thomas, and have sent him the following reply:

> Hello Sam,
>
> For me actually understand what you're suggesting, can you please
> first tell me about your site? One can't just arbitrarily put links in
> StackExchange answers, after all; nor can one simply post
> advertisement messages. SE answers need to be valid answers to
> questions people have.
>
> Eyal

A few days pass, and he writes me back: (I'm altering the URL he gave me, replacing `com` at the end with `notreally` so as not to actually link there):

> of course. The site is [www.1stidental.notreally](http://www.1stidental.notreally).
> The technologies used in the include a variety of html css
> components, ajax calls, mysql, javascript, etc.
> Please let me know if interested or if you have any questions.

visiting the site, it's not a site *about* some technology, or software product, or anything like that - it's a dental clinic in Brooklyn, of all things. That guy's scheme is looking less and less solid by the minute.

Should I do anything else? Like, try to get him to reveal details? Or should I just let it go and let him fail on his own?

Comment: You're sure to get the taxonomist badge for [dental-clinics-in-brooklyn] :) But I think at this point you should let it go?

Comment: @CDR: I wonder... if I use the actual URL here, and get some upvotes, perhaps this will count as having earned my $100 ? :-P

Comment: I've already seen spam from this clinic here on MSE.

Comment: @AugustoVasques: That is so weird... unless somehow a lot of people on MSE happen to live in Brooklyn. The secret cabal?

Comment: There's a reason we all fit into a small new york apartment...

Comment: @einsupportsModeratorStrike. As weird as this [SPAM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388909/what-are-some-highly-recommended-indian-restaurants-in-brampton-that-offer-authe) that is specifically targeted towards Brampton residents who enjoy Curry.

Comment: @AugustoVasques this is deleted, how can you see it?

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack https://imgur.com/a/lTHm9Ki

Comment: @AugustoVasques smart way to keep track of posts. :D

Comment: @AugustoVasques: "Explore a modern technique for cultivating vegetables" - pay someone on StackExchange to do it for you.

Comment: Re *"counter-fish"*: Do you mean *"counter-[phish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing)"*?

Comment: So he wanted you to bite.

Comment: I'll never encourage engaging with someone you don't know who's behaving suspiciously, but you should at least be aware that I'm skeptical it would surface information that would be useful to staff. As far as things go from our side, probably this kind of scamming isn't something we could even start to practically investigate unless it starts to happen a _lot_ (though we do keep an eye on things when we get reports like this).

Comment: The Scambaiting  community (of which I was a part for many years) insist that the first rule is be safe. That means not using your real-life info at any point, hiding your location etc.. I can't help but notice your profile info has everything but your address. Smoe scammers may not seem sophisticated, but bear in mind they are potentially connected to a multi-billion dollar international network of ruthless people. By posting this as yourself, you are exposing yourself to unknown but potentially very serious dangers.

Comment: Cont.: If you're interested in learning more, check-out [419eater.com](https://www.419eater.com/), the largest and most ethical Scambaiting community on this planet. It's fun.

Comment: @W.O. did someone pay you to post the link? :P

Comment: @bobeyt6isstricken: He did it as a favor to a Nigerian prince.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum I think that OP is referring to [catfishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catfishing), so the spelling is correct.

Comment: If you are looking for curious spam, Charcoal's archive database [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/) has some pearls. From the oddly specific, if you want your gutters cleaned or you garage door unstuck, we have I think three dozen small companies in Houston who can help you with that which all spammed us within a few days a couple of years back. Among the regulars, witch doctors who can cast a spell on your behalf and invitations to join the African arm of the Illuminati would be the funniest, if it weren't for the fact that some poor souls are apparently falling for these scams

Comment: They keep promissing, if I do just a little bit more for them they'll pay. @bobeyt6isstricken

Answer (score 11):

FWIW, this sort of thing isn't new - there are brokers who coordinate posting and verification; the business being advertised may have no idea that this is being done.

This case is interesting primarily because they reached out to you instead farming it out to folks who post this sort of thing all day.

In the past, the best way to mitigate this was to allow the posts to be up on the site for a little bit (long enough for the author to submit the URL for credit, not long enough for them to be verified) and then delete them

If you're into it, I'd push this as far as possible without revealing anything personal - see what sort of details you can drag out, particularly as to the verification process.

Comment: What (more) personal information would I reveal? You mean a bank account maybe? He won't need my physical address.

Comment: Bank account is exactly what I had in mind 

Comment: What is the logic behind that mitigation strategy? You rob the person who actually does the spamming of the payment for their work, thus disincentivizing them from doing so in the future? Why would that be more effective than just removing it ASAP?

Comment: The logic is, a sufficiently determined spammer will always find a way past your defences, @Cody - they're getting paid to succeed, while success always costs us time and potentially other resources. If we can make it less profitable for them and no more expensive for us, they eventually seek greener pastures. I forget what delay I used - probably somewhere around 10 minutes - but it seemed to reduce frequency pretty quickly vs instant blocks (which got worked around in minutes) or hours (which kept working but didn't seem to slow the flood).

Comment: (that said, I'm going from memory of scripts I used years ago, so all bets are off - good chance both the spammers and verification strategies have evolved significantly)

Comment: @ein If you want to pursue this further, you might want to consider temporarily hiding your MSE account in case they go looking for your posts.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say: feel free to waste their time, but that costs you time also, so is it worth it?

I would be nice of course if they were interacting with a lot of potential victims who *all* waste their time (a sort of reverse spamming/denial of service), but that's unlikely.

On a side note: I'm still waiting for the Microsoft help desk to call me so that I can say 'Let me get my partner, she handles these things', and then put down the phone and do nothing.